# How to download any type file on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8

In a Windows 8 application, I've figured out how to download a file with a browser. I have used `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)`. The browser opens and asks the user to save or open the file.

But I want to download a file to disk/storage within a Windows 8 application. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Is it that you want to download a file from within your application, without opening the browser?

Comment: Yeah,I want to download a file from within my application.

Comment: J.S.D. M, I edited your question to be more readable. Please take some time to read the StackOverflow FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially the 'how to ask' section: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: Peter, what does J.S.M. stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download a file in the background. Please look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61) sample.

Comment: Also change the localhost path to something else. You need to mess around with command lines to make that work. By default it throws a messy exception.

PS:it saves files to PicturesLibrary.

Comment: @Milan Aggarwal Would you be willing to share the code for downloading an unknown file(like pptx,xslx) to any folder. I would be really interested in looking at that.